# DNS search path on Windows

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN on a Linux box and I need a method to push this setting to client, in order to be able reach machine.example.com within *.example.com.I've tried to use openvpn's config to do this, and seem that if the client is using Windows isn't working.

In order to solve this, I need a bat file to change dns search path on windows client machine after vpn connection establishment.

Answer (score 1):

`wmic nicconfig where "description='NAME OF THE ADAPTER HERE'" call setdnsserversearchorder("10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2")`

To see all the fun other stuff you can do with this class (Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration), see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx) or check out the method docs.

`wmic nicconfig call /?`

EDIT: As I pointed out later, you probably want one of these instead:

`wmic nicconfig where "description='NAME OF THE ADAPTER HERE'" call setdnsdomain("yourdomain.tld")` (so yourdomain.tld is like "microsoft.com" in the official documentation).

OR

If you want to change the order of domains you search (if you have a bunch, you try `setdnssuffixsearchorder()`.

`wmic nicconfig where "description='NAME OF THE ADAPTER HERE'" call setdnssuffixsearchorder("yourdomain1.tld", "yourdomain2.tld")`

If you want to apply this to every card or adapter, you can just say anyone that is not null.  I have not tested this and do not know the impact on the OS and VPN-based virtual adapters on your system, so **please test that *before* destroying a production box).**  So, revisit the above example.

`wmic nicconfig where "description=!=null" call setdnssuffixsearchorder("yourdomain1.tld", "yourdomain2.tld")`

Again, look at the caveat above.  So, if you want this in a quick and dirty batch file, just do something like this (for a specific adapter at this point, I want you to know if you need to apply to all before you copy one of my half-assed scripts.  I made[a pretty junky one for you on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/636nPB01).  I hope it helps.  I have dumped it to the screen below.  Make sure to "quote your adapter name" and quote "your domain name" when using the batch file, or it will be most unfun with the crazy results that will bork your computer.

```
@ECHO OFF

IF NOT %1=="" GOTO CHECKPARAM

ECHO You did not mention an adapter for me to configure.
ECHO Goodbye!
GOTO :EOF

:CHECKPARAM

REM Make sure that other than setting the adapter name,
REM you actually have a domain set.

IF NOT %2=="" GOTO CONFIGDNS

ECHO You did not supply a domain you want configured.
ECHO Goodbye!
GOTO :EOF

:CONFIGDNS

%WINDIR%\system32\wmic.exe nicconifg "where description='%~1'" call setdnsdomain("%~2")

IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 GOTO :EOF

ECHO Uh-oh. WMIC seems to have not exited gracefully.
ECHO The error code was %ERRORLEVEL%.
ECHO Goodbye!

:EOF
```

Comment: Sorry I was lazy and forgot the original post, but holler back if you are not sure how to include this into a batch script.

Comment: And like an idiot, I think what you really need is `setdnsdomain()` or `setdnssuffixsearchorder()`.

Comment: I'm getting  ERROR:
Code = 0x80041017
Description = Invalid query
Facility = WMI   when I try your example in a single line test.bat file.(I'm not a windows sysadmin and I'm a bit confused )

Comment: I amended my answer to make it clearer.  I hope some more advanced people can point you in the right direction if I am way off.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that using `wmic`, but I'm not sure how.

Every version of Windows also has an option called something like [Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305553) that might help.